# Data is Null error in GetDateTime()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Still.I get an error on this part.(another part of my codes where I really want to do is to put `IsDBNull` on it)
But the I know it'll not work in `GetDateTime`. Is there any possible solution?

```
data[key].ApproverList.Add(
    new Approver() {
                        RequestID = key,
                        FullName = reader.IsDBNull(27) ? null : reader.GetString(27),
                        ApproveDate = reader.GetDateTime(28)
                   });
```

same as the

`FullName` with `reader.IsDBNull(27) ? null : reader.GetString(27)`

how about

```
ApproveDate = reader.GetDateTime(28)
```

What will be in here?

Comment: You'd better provide more info about your code, what's reader's type? how it's initialized?

Comment: can you make `ApproveDate`  nullable?

Comment: @Rebornix it is an SqlReader reader.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh that's what I am about to ask ..

Comment: If you can make it nullable, your code'll not break even if `reader.GetDateTime(28)` returns null. or you might want to assign some default DateTime value to your `ApprovedDate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DateTime? startingDate;

if !reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("STARTINGDATE"))
{
    startingDate = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("STARTINGDATE"));
}
else
{
    startingDate = null;
}
```

I know you are leaving ..

Comment: `ApproveDate` is nullable now?